# Nodemon can't create a local server path, after upgrading libraries

Tags: node.js, flask, whatsapp, localtunnel

After update some libraries in Python the second console can't create the path to point out my local server which I was using to send messages from whatsapp.

1. console: It's Ok

```
nodemon main.py --verbose
```

2. console: Get stuck

```
nodemon --watch "main.py" --exec "lt --subdomain asgeir --port 5000" --delay 2
```

It is supposed to print:

> `[nodemon] starting lt --subdomain asgeir --port 5000` 
> `your url is https://asgeir.loca.lt ...`

But nothing happens. It got stuck creating the path - it was working correctly after those updates. And the problem is that I can't fix it because I don't know exactly what packages, are getting the error. I've just reinstalled everything, tried out using previous versions, create virtual environments etc. with any results.

The next file is ok, and the list of current packages and libraries used(after updating) are:

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["get","post"])
def reply():
    res= MessagingResponse()
    res.message('Hello')
    return str("res")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

```
Python             3.10.5, 
node               v16.16.0
```

```
npm list -g
+-- localtunnel@2.0.0
`-- nodemon@2.0.19
```

Python packages used are:

```
twilio             7.11.0
pymongo            4.1.1
Flask              2.1.3
dnspython          2.2.1
```

Hope someone would help, cheers.

Comment: https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel/issues/509 Check this url. You are doing everything alright, just that local tunnel is down for now. Nobody knows when it comes back. You can use ngrok.